# Combine query results from two tables that aren't connected to each other but have same foreign keys in to 1 query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to do some statistics on application usage. I have 2 models that are hoarding the data:

PullLog

```
id
user_id
foo_id 
bar_id 
created_at
```

RestateLog

```
id
user_id
foo_id 
change_to 
created_at
```

Foo

- has_many pull_logs
- has_many restate_logs

User

- has_many pull_logs
- has_many restate_logs

Example data I need to retrieve are as follows:

- how many pull_logs have user done?
- how many restate_logs have user done?

I'm using rails 6 and postgres and preferably I would like to express this queries in Active record

I came up with 2 queries:

```
SELECT
    pull_logs.user_id,
    count(pull_logs.user_id) as user_pull_logs_count,
    count(bar.id) FILTER ( WHERE bar.uuid = 'uuid') as example_bar_count
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE pull_logs.bar_id IS NULL) as direct_problems_count
FROM
    problem_pull_logs
LEFT JOIN 
    bar ON pull_logs.bar_id = bar.id
GROUP BY
    pull_logs.user_id
```

Second SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS restate_count,
    COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'to_call' ) as to_call_count,
    COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'success' ) as to_success_count,
    COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'canceled' ) as to_canceled_count
FROM
    restate_logs
GROUP BY
    restate_logs.user_id
```

Is there a way to combine this 2 queries?

I would also like to retrieve data like:

- how many pull_logs have user done by day?

or

- how many pull_logs have user done by bar_id?

I also need to have possibility to add filters like retrieving data only for a given user or only for a given day or bar_id

Edit : sample data:

pull_log

```
id: 1 ; foo_id: 1 ; user_id: 2 ; bar_id: 1 ; created_at: 2019-09-17  
id: 2 ; foo_id: 1 ; user_id: 2 ; bar_id: 1 ; created_at: 2019-09-18  
id: 3 ; foo_id: 2 ; user_id: 1 ; bar_id: 2 ; created_at: 2019-09-18
```

restate_log

```
id: 1 ; foo_id: 1 ; user_id: 2 ; change_to: "to_call" ; created_at: 2019-09-17  
id: 2 ; foo_id: 1 ; user_id: 2 ; change_to: "success" ; created_at: 2019-09-18  
id: 3 ; foo_id: 2 ; user_id: 1 ; change_to: "to_call" ; created_at: 2019-09-18
```

Expected results:

```
user_id 1  
pull_count 1  
pull_from_bar_1_count 0  
pull_from_bar_2_count 1  
restate_count  1  
restate_to_call_count 1  
restate_to_success_count 0  

user_id 2  
pull_count 2  
pull_from_bar_1_count 2  
pull_from_bar_2_count 0  
restate_count 2  
restate_to_call_count 1  
restate_to_success_count 1
```

EDIT:
After answer from GMB

I ported this two queries to ActiveRecord as follows:

```
def pull_logs
    PullLog.select(<<-SQL.squish
      pull_logs.user_id as user_id,
      count(pull_logs.user_id) as user_pull_logs_count,
      count(foo.id) FILTER (
        WHERE foo.uuid = '66ca4921-b66b-47d8-bd75-5c1ac8e92118'
      ) as foo_1_count,
      count(*) FILTER (WHERE pull_logs.foo_id IS NULL)
        as direct_count
      SQL
      ).joins(<<-SQL.squish
      LEFT JOIN foo
      ON pull_logs.foo_id = foo.id
      SQL
      ).group("pull_logs.user_id")
      .order("pull_logs.user_id")
  end

def restate_logs
    RestateLog.select(<<-SQL.squish
      restate_logs.user_id,
      COUNT(*) AS restate_count,
      COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'to_call' ) as to_call_count,
      COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'success' ) as to_success_count,
      COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'canceled' ) as to_canceled_count
      SQL
      ).group("restate_logs.user_id")
      .order("restate_logs.user_id")
  end
```

I combine this 2 queries in

```
Model.select("*")
      .from(<<-SQL.squish
        (#{pull_logs}) as pull_logs
        LEFT JOIN (#{restate_logs}) as restate_logs
        ON pull_logs.user_id = restate_logs.user_id)
        SQL
      )
```

I wonder If there may be a simpler way to combine results to present them in single table view?

Comment: Combine how? Show us sample data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve] first of all.

Comment: @jarlh I added sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

Combining the queries will not be easy, since they adress different tables and do aggregation. A simple way to proceed, without digging into the functional aspects of the queries, would be to `JOIN` the results of both queries on the user id. This assumes that all users do have results in both queries:

```
SELECT 
    pl.*,
    rl.restate_count,
    rl.to_call_count,
    rl.to_success_count
    rl.to_canceled_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        pull_logs.user_id,
        count(pull_logs.user_id) as user_pull_logs_count,
        count(bar.id) FILTER ( WHERE bar.uuid = 'uuid') as example_bar_count
        count(*) FILTER (WHERE pull_logs.bar_id IS NULL) as direct_problems_count
    FROM
        problem_pull_logs
    LEFT JOIN bar ON pull_logs.bar_id = bar.id
    GROUP BY
        pull_logs.user_id
    ) pl
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        COUNT(*) AS restate_count,
        COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'to_call' ) as to_call_count,
        COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'success' ) as to_success_count,
        COUNT(*) FILTER ( WHERE restate_logs.change_to = 'canceled' ) as to_canceled_count
    FROM
        restate_logs
    GROUP BY
        restate_logs.user_id
) rl ON rl.user_id = pl.user_id
```